# If $Q$ is a p.s.d. matrix and $x^TQx = 0$, then must $Qx = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

I am reading a textbook which seems to imply that if $Q$ is a positive semidefinite matrix (not necesarily symmetric) and $x^TQx = 0$, then $x \in \text{Null}(Q).$ This seems a little suspicious to me, so to find a counterexample I tried to following: I tried looking for a vector $x$ and a $2 \times 2$ matrix $Q$ so that
$$Q \begin{bmatrix} x_1\\x_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -x_2 \\x_1 \end{bmatrix}$$
If we find a non-zero $x$ and a p.s.d. $Q$ which satisfy the above equation, then we have a counterexample. However, I was not succesfull.

Is the proposition actually true, or is there a counterexample?

Comment: Why not choose Q as the operator of 90° rotation? This gives $x^TQx=0$ for every x, but $Qx=0$ only for $x=0$.

Comment: @LeechLattice Thanks, makes sense. Do you think this would be true if we assume $Q$ symmetric? This is a very strange situation, since my Optimization book really seems to claim this.

Comment: @Ovi For a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix, we do have that $x^TQx=0$ if and only if $v^TQx$ for all $v$, if and only if $x\in \ker Q$. The second "if and only if" is universally true for matrices. The first one comes from Cauchy-Schwarz $$(v^TQx)^2\le (x^TQx)(v^TAv)$$

Comment: @Gae.S. Thanks, that's great! The proof is more tricky than I expected though.

Comment: @Ovi Is it? I thought it was essentially just the fact that $as^2+bs+c\ge 0$ for all $s$ if and only if $$(a>0\land b^2-4ac\le0)\lor (a=0\land b=0\land c\ge0)$$ plus the observation that $a=0\land b=0$ implies $b^2-4ac\le 0$ as well.

Comment: @Gae.S. Your way is very interesting to me but I'm having trouble seeing the connection between showing $(x^TQx = 0 \implies Qx = 0)$ and your logical statements. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Well, you know that $(v+sx)^TQ(v+sx)\ge 0$ for all $s\in\Bbb R$. Expand and it becomes $v^TQv+2sv^TQx+s^2x^TQx\ge0$ for all $s\in\Bbb R$. The condition $b^2-4ac\le0$ is Cauchy-Schwarz. Once you have Cauchy-Schwarz, the rest is as I said before (of course, CS is $(v^TQx)^2\le (x^TQx)(v^TQv)$; there is a typo).

Comment: @Gae.S. Thanks! I think we don't need to invoke Cauchy-Schwarz at all, since as you said, knowing that $\forall s: as^2 + bs + c \ge 0$ already gives us $(b^2 - 4ac \le 0) \vee (a = 0 \wedge b = 0 \wedge c \ge 0).$  The tricky part of me is thinking to examine the quadratic form $(v+sx)^TQ(v+sx)$ in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose $Q$ as
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}

**SHARE IDEA: How can we choose such matrix?**
Note that we can consider $Qx$ as an image of $x$ through a transformation.
Now, we see that
$$x^TQx=x \cdot (Qx)$$
Follow your idea, we aim to choose $Q$ such that the dot product between $x$ and its image is non-negative and equal to $0$ for some non-zero $x$. Thus, the transformation can be chosen as a $90^o$-rotation. So, we obtain $Q$ as above.