# If $Q$ is symmetric, p.s.d, and $x^TQx = 0$ for some $x$, then $Qx= 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I recently asked [the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3802986/if-q-is-a-p-s-d-matrix-and-xtqx-0-then-must-qx-0?noredirect=1#comment7838332_3802986), except it did not have the symmetry hypothesis. The user Gae. S. was kind enough to prove the statement with the symmetry hypothesis in the comments. For me, altough short, the proof was somewhat unintuitive (I didn't get the motivation for the first step), so I am wondering whether there are different proofs, or whether it's possible possible to cast this proof in a more intuitive light.

The proof by Gae. S. is:

Take an $x$ with $x^TQx = 0$ and let $v$ be an arbitrary vector, $s$ an arbitrary scalar. Since $Q$ is positive semidefinite,
$$(v+sx)^TQ(v+sx) = v^TQv + 2sv^TQx + s^2x^TQx\ge 0$$
Since $x^TQx = 0$, and the inequality holds for all $s$, we must also have $v^TQx = 0$. Since this equality holds for all $v$, we must also have $x = 0$.

Comment: If $Q$ is symmetric p.s.d, it has a symmetric square root $S$ (i.e. such that $S^2 = Q$). Then $0 =x^TQx = (Sx)^T(Sx)$, so you deduce $Sx= 0$, so $Qx=0$.

Comment: Suppose $Q$ is a non-negative self-adjoint linear operator defined on a finite or infinite dimensional inner product space. Then $\langle u,v\rangle_Q=\langle Qu,v\rangle$ defines a semi-inner product. If $\langle Qx,x\rangle=0$, put $y=Qx$. By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $|\langle Qx,Qx\rangle|^2=|\langle x,y\rangle_Q|^2\le\langle x,x\rangle_Q\langle y,y\rangle_Q=\langle Qx,x\rangle\langle y,y\rangle_Q=0$. Therefore $\langle Qx,Qx\rangle$ must be zero and in turn $Qx=0$.

Comment: @xpaul Yes I wanted either another solution, or the motivation behind thinking to examine $(v+sx)^TQ(v+sx)$ for arbitrary $s, v$ in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for the solutions